# after making changes in defaultDatalayer option in gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager , getting unexpected token '['

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to solve the rogue referral problem using the gatsby tagmanager plugin in my `gatsby-config.js`  by doing the following:

```js
{
    resolve:'gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager',
    options:{
        id: process.env.GTM_ID,
        includeInDevelopment: true ,
        defaultDataLayer: function() {
            return {
                 originalLocation: document.location.protocol +
                 "//" + document.location.hostname +
                 document.location.pathname + 
                 document.location.search
            }
        }
    }
}
```

everything seems to work fine, the link is coming in datalayer before gtm is fired and start, but for some links in my SPA i am getting this error:

```
Uncaught syntaxError: unexpected token '['
  at gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX:489:414
  at b (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX:490:337)
  at pe (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX:87:769)
  at e (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX:245:34)
  at Array.<anonymus>(gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX:246:434)
  at object.execute(gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXXX:246:434)
```

Comment: Have you checked your `GTM_ID`? Is it containing any weird character?

Comment: @FerranBuireu yeah GTM_ID is set in .env file ,and has no weired character